# When I remove the scheme when linking to my jQuery file it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This doesn't work:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

This works:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the page scheme is `file:///` -

Comment: The link is https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: Are you clicking on the html page on your C drive? You can only use the protocol relative path if you are on http (webserver). You should run a local webserver since developing off the file protocol causes the browser to run in a different way.

Comment: Check your console and network tabs in your browser's developer tools. Look at the lines in red. We're guessing you're getting a 404 or similar error.